# Wordpress - Products without price go to the bottom when sorting by price ASC

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a built-in filter in my WooCommerce for ordering my products by price. When I choose to order them by price ascending, the products without price comes all the way to the top. I want these products to be right at the bottom of the page. Any suggestions?

PS I've only managed to hide these products from the list with this code in my functions.php file:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'shop_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );
function shop_only_instock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {


    if( is_admin() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => '',
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '!='
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => 0,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '!='
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

UPDATE: 8 days later I am still struggling with this one. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: show your code . So that we can help you

Comment: You have to make a `where` clause with explicit that ignore prices where `price == 0.00`

Comment: I have only managed to hide these products with code in my functions.php file and this is not even close to what I have asked. That is why I didn't paste my code here.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I have shown my code. Can you help?

Comment: @Doorman sorry looks like I also can’t help on this. Sorry